# Is the Mil Mi-2 still in production?

Tags: military, helicopter, russia

I have read conflicting reports that this Russian helicopter is out of production, yet others say otherwise. Could anyone confirm?

Comment: For those reading this questions in few years, you may precise the current date into your question.

Comment: Both [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-2) and [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-2) Wiki say that the production of the Mi-2 ended in 1998. They refer to this [russian document](http://avia.cybernet.name/hel/model/mi-2.html). Where did you get the information from that it is still in production?

Comment: @PerlDuck The russian document also says (Google translated to English): "In 2005, another 11 helicopters are planned to be manufactured for Indonesia.". The document only lists the total number of produced helicopters for the time from 1965 to 1998, but that does not necessarily mean production stopped then.

Comment: @Bianfable, it rather doesn't mean production resumed. You can safely discount any such 'plans' until you see that it actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

Mi-2 was almost entirely produced in Poland, on [PZL-Świdnik](http://pzl.swidnik.pl/pzl_en/index.html). That production officially ended in [1992](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8-2).

Since then, a few new modifications/prototypes may have been produced, according to various sources, but they were almost certainly retrofits of the existing airframes.

In 2012, it was [announced](http://interfax.com/newsinf.asp?id=307416) that production of a modernised Mi-2A would start in China, but I could not find any confirmation that it actually happened. Frankly, I see no good reason why it would. Generally, any announcement of plans from Russia in the last 30 years should be treated with extreme caution and not considered valid without confirmation.